# How to enable stem language in php?

Tags: php, stem

I have installed porter stemmer:

```
pecl install stem

...

Compile Danish stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile Dutch stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile English stemmer? [yes] : y
Compile Finnish stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile French stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile German stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile Hungarian stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile Italian stemmer? [yes] : y
Compile Norwegian stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile Portuguese stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile Romanian stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile Russian stemmer? [yes] : y
Compile Russian (UTF8) stemmer? [yes] : y
Compile Spanish stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile Swedish stemmer? [yes] : n
Compile Turkish (UTF8) stemmer? [yes] : n
```

I have added

```
extension=stem.so
```

string in the end of php.ini file and ...

```
service apache2 restart
```

But phpinfo shows me:

```
stem
stem support    enabled
version     1.5.1
compiled as dynamic module
Languages Supported
Original Porter     enabled (default)
Danish  disabled
Dutch   disabled
English     disabled
Finnish     disabled
French  disabled
German  disabled
Hungarian   disabled
Italian     disabled
Norwegian   disabled
Portuguese  disabled
Romanian    disabled
Russian     disabled
Russian (Unicode)   disabled
Spanish     disabled
Swedish     disabled
Turkish (Unicode)   disabled
```

...and function stem_english does not exists.

How to enable languages?

P.S.: And this text I have to insert to avoid "looks like mostly code" error. Moderators can remove it.

Comment: make sure that you've enabled the extension using `phpenmod` then restart your apache2

Comment: Added stem.so to  post.   "php5enmod stem"  does not help.

Answer (score 1):

A-ha-ha, I should type "yes" or "no", not "y" or "n". The solution is:

```
pecl stem uninstall 
pecl stem install

Compile Danish stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile Dutch stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile English stemmer? [yes] : yes
Compile Finnish stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile French stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile German stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile Hungarian stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile Italian stemmer? [yes] : yes
Compile Norwegian stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile Portuguese stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile Romanian stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile Russian stemmer? [yes] : yes
Compile Russian (UTF8) stemmer? [yes] : yes
Compile Spanish stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile Swedish stemmer? [yes] : no
Compile Turkish (UTF8) stemmer? [yes] : no
```